# Why doesn't Linux protect memory like Windows?

Tags: windows, memory

When I run a piece of code which uses a huge amount of memory, like this:

```py
a = "1"
while True:a+=a
```

in Windows 10, it gives me `memory error` and the computer remains safe, but running exactly this code in Linux causes freezing and uses up the memory. Why doesn't it give me `memory error`?

Comment: What language is this written in and how do you run it on Linux?

Comment: looks like Python to me

Comment: "protect memory" is wildly unclear as a description. Linux _does_ do many things within the bounds of what security practitioners think of as "memory protection", for example. If you mean to ask why Linux doesn't kill your process when you it tries to allocate more memory than you have physical RAM, _ask that_.

Comment: (...but generally, the answer will depend on how you decided to configure that system during setup: if you configured it with a bunch of swap, then presumably you did that _because_ you wanted it to move pages out of memory to disk when no more memory was available, and preferred the risk of the system becoming extremely slow to the risk of operations failing outright; if that's not what you wanted, then you shouldn't have configured it thusly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linux kernel OOM handling is quite poor and Linux kernel developers have made it clear that this issue should be tackled in userspace: https://lkml.org/lkml/2019/8/4/15

As for userspace you're free to use:

- `cgroups`
- `limits.conf`
- `earlyoom`, `nohang` and similar applications: https://github.com/hakavlad/nohang

Distros like Fedora now include `earlyoom` by default.

Update October, 2022:

Nowadays `systemd-oomd` must be enabled for you is you're using a fresh enough distribution. If you don't have it installed, you may install `earlyoom` manually (must be available in repos of most distros or could be compiled).

Comment: Doesn't look "quite clear" to me. Fascinating thread, by the way. The conclusion seemed to be "let's try it" but I'm not up on current kernel status

Comment: The thread has been abandoned and no real work has been done to tackle the issue.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. That's a shame

Comment: I tried OP's code on Debian Buster amd64, 4G RAM, no swap, Python 3.7.3, for about 7 minutes, but I had no freezing. Memory usage dropped actually, from 1.94GB to 1.90GB (had other applications open also, but left them as is).  Does Debian enable a protective mechanism also?

Comment: @Krackout, that "no swap" is critical. Swapping is typically what makes things so slow as to seem frozen.